# How do I print a table inside a popup dialog with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I currently have a popup dialog with a timetable inside it and a button below. When pressed it should print the timetable inside that dialog.

What I've done so far is: `<input type="submit" value="Print Timetable" class="ActionButton" onClick="window.print()"/>` but it prints the entire page. I'm not sure how I can print just the table inside it.

I've also noticed that in print preview. there are no colours. It's black and white.

I'm using jQuery and PHP as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a print stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Create CSS rules to hide the content you do not what to be printed. Format the popup so it looks pretty.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm